# How can I make the text change size with the image using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have already added the necessary code to make the image expand when someone hovers over it but now I want to make the text expand with the image.

```js
function big(d) {
  d.style.height = "200px";
  d.style.width = "200px";
}

function normal(d) {
  d.style.height = "54px";
  d.style.width = "54px";
}
```

```html
<img class="audioimg" onmouseover="big(this)" onmouseout="normal(this)" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/276/200/300.jpg?hmac=5VSJJxPMnu25ukKlrNc0y2KxLtG_jF7BfA13IlTm0uo" alt="ugly" width="54px" height="54px">
<p class="audiotext" id="audiotext1"> text </p>
```

Comment: You can't set the fontSize on it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done and what attempts you've made based on that research.

Comment: You should be able to use `d.nextElementSibling.style.fontSize` in your functions, assuming the text is always in an element immediately following the image.

Comment: `this` is the image so you would need to select the `p`. If the code you listed will always look like this than you can select the sibling, if it will not, you might ant to use some sort of selector and look up the element.

Comment: why would you use js for this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use JS for this kind of thing. You can scale Images with `scale()` in CSS. I used the `:hover` trigger for a wrapper-element to scale all images and text inside it.

```css
.wrap:hover img {
  transform: scale(3);
}

.wrap:hover p {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img class="audioimg" src="image.jpg" alt="ugly" width="54px" height="54px">
  <p class="audiotext" id="audiotext1"> text </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming his HTML is always formatted like his example, you can just use the adjacent sibling selector instead of using a parent `wrap` class. `img:hover + p`

Comment: There are multiple ways of targetting the elements. You can also add a class to the image and target it with `img.theClass + p` This depends on the available structure and what exactly the goal of OP is.